# Totalizar sobre datatable, incluyendo filtros

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Tengo una DataTable con ciertas columnas, una de ellas es `Cantidad`.
Esta columna se me ha pedido realizar una totalización, lo cual es simple el contar todas las filas y sumarlas. Pero MI complicación viene con los detalles.

Debe contabilizarse incluso usando el filtro de búsqueda, y descontando los equipos con estado ANULADO.

Ya he intentado totalizar, pero no logro aplicarlo sobre el filtro además.

Entonces lo que necesito, es un modo de realizar la totalización en tiempo real, de modo que si aplico algún filtro sobre la tabla, la totalización cambie y recalcule todo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#general').DataTable();
  $('#general tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
      table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.23/af-2.3.5/b-1.6.5/b-colvis-1.6.5/b-flash-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/cr-1.5.3/fc-3.3.2/fh-3.1.8/kt-2.6.1/r-2.2.7/rg-1.1.2/rr-1.2.7/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.1/sp-1.2.2/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.23/af-2.3.5/b-1.6.5/b-colvis-1.6.5/b-flash-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/cr-1.5.3/fc-3.3.2/fh-3.1.8/kt-2.6.1/r-2.2.7/rg-1.1.2/rr-1.2.7/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.1/sp-1.2.2/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<table id="general">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>MONICA ERIKA GARCIA RUBIO</td>
      <td>ANULADO</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EDUARDO TARANTINO</td>
      <td>ACTIVO</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MONICA ERIKA GARCIA RUBIO</td>
      <td>ACTIVO</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MONICA ERIKA GARCIA RUBIO</td>
      <td>ACTIVO</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EDUARDO TARANTINO</td>
      <td>ANULADO</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfooter>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>TOTAL:</td>
      <td>ACAVAELTOTAL</td>
    </tr>
  </tfooter>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#general').DataTable({
        dom: 'f'
      });
    });
  </script>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿No te sirve el evento [search](https://datatables.net/reference/event/search)?

Comment: @JonatanLavado Veré si me funciona para lo que quiero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es usar drawCallback para sumar, te dejo un ejemplo de tu mismo código

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.23/af-2.3.5/b-1.6.5/b-colvis-1.6.5/b-flash-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/cr-1.5.3/fc-3.3.2/fh-3.1.8/kt-2.6.1/r-2.2.7/rg-1.1.2/rr-1.2.7/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.1/sp-1.2.2/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.23/af-2.3.5/b-1.6.5/b-colvis-1.6.5/b-flash-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/cr-1.5.3/fc-3.3.2/fh-3.1.8/kt-2.6.1/r-2.2.7/rg-1.1.2/rr-1.2.7/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.1/sp-1.2.2/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<table id="general">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>MONICA ERIKA GARCIA RUBIO</td>
      <td>ANULADO</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EDUARDO TARANTINO</td>
      <td>ACTIVO</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MONICA ERIKA GARCIA RUBIO</td>
      <td>ACTIVO</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MONICA ERIKA GARCIA RUBIO</td>
      <td>ACTIVO</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EDUARDO TARANTINO</td>
      <td>ANULADO</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfooter>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>TOTAL:</td>
      <td id="total">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tfooter>
  <script>

function mostrar()
{
    $('#general tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
      } else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
      }
    });
}


var table=$('#general').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings  ) {
        var e=settings.nTBody.rows;
        $("#total").html("");
        var total=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            var a=e[i]["innerText"];
                var porciones = a.split("\t");
                var total=total+parseFloat(porciones[2]);               
        }
        $("#total").html(total);
      mostrar();
    }
} );


    
  </script>
</table>
```

Te dará como resultado algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Recuerda que debes reiniciar el total cada que realices una búsqueda o filtrar por lo que deseas

Para Filtrar por lo que deseas para sumar solo los activos colocas una condición dentro del drawCallback

```
$('#general').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings  ) {
        var e=settings.nTBody.rows;
        $("#total").html("");
        var total=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            var a=e[i]["innerText"];
                var porciones = a.split("\t");
                var total=total+parseFloat(porciones[2]);               
        }
        $("#total").html(total);
    }
} );
```

Llamas así a al Datatable y cada que cambies borrara la cuenta y volverá a sumar.

Comment: Recuerda reiniciar tu suma cada que busques o hagas un filtro, pero ya son detalles que puedes mejorar, ya tienes la lógica

Comment: Ya te hago un ejemplo

Comment: Verifica el ejemplo que te puse

Comment: Debes borrar todo datatable, osea con ese llamas al datatable y con ese mismo sumas

Comment: Como este ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/afrv7eok/

Comment: No te entiendo mucho.. algo asi? https://jsfiddle.net/zj4ysao6/

Comment: Correcto!!! lo tuviste que convertir en funcion ?? Ahora solo queda aplicar el filtro de activos ??

Comment: Si en funcion, como te dije es fácil, ya tienes la logica.. solo es que lo acomodes como desees

Comment: Por favor, edita la respuesta con el ultimo ejemplo, me ha funcionado ;)

Comment: Escribe "ACTIVOS" en la busqueda y veras que se filtra

Comment: Me sirve y todo, pero hay un momento en que las clases del select, como que las pierde.  Alguna idea de esto ultimo ?? https://i.gyazo.com/76967c15428db806faa451ce625916f3.mp4

Comment: Puede ser porque lo haces con JS hazlo mejor con CSS, en tu header, asi evitas eso

Comment: Nap, no puedo agregar tu totalización junto al resto de mis scripts. Me sigue diciendo que la tabla se reinicializa, pero no quiero borrar el resto de scripts. Buscaré como solucionar eso, pero tu respuesta es correcta para totalizar igual.

Comment: Recuerda que te dije que solo debe hacer un datatable con id general, no pueden haber 2

Comment: Solo hay una, es por eso que no entiendo cuando cree duplicarse.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130942/discussion-between-josue-vargas-and-excorpion).

Comment: Pude finalmente aplicarlo correctamente !!!